# CSS width doesn't apply when cloning html code via .html()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, width

I have a hidden div containing a form (display: none;).

I use jsPanel (jQuery plugin) to have modal popups inside my window.
When the modal pops up I copy the code of the hidden div inside the model by using .html()

**The code is properly copied**, but the css width property doesn't apply properly. The form inside the div does not use 100% of its parent container (the div of the jspanel).

Any idea why ?

Comment: So it has got the attribute `style="width:100%;"` . Perhaps it doesn't rescale when added to match parent. Can you post a jsfiddle?

Comment: yes that's exactly whats happening, it doesn't rescale. I'll try to add a jsfiddle in a few hours

Comment: On the fiddle I can't add jsPanel library, but you got all the css there so you understand: https://jsfiddle.net/y6kxbfgL/2/
@ahervin

Comment: There must be some conflicting CSS to a parent element on the jsPanel as the form when copied still has CSS affecting it.

Comment: ok, I figured out that table tag should inherit something wrong. I encapsuled the table in a simple <div style="width:100%;"> and now it works. Thanks for your help anyway :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<table> width was conflicting with jsPanel properties.
```

Englobing the table into

```
<div style="width:100%;">
```

fix the issue.